# How can i use multi hashtags on facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, api, fb.ui

I am using fb.ui to share on facebook whith a hashtag

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: url,
    hashtag: '#TestHash1'
}, function(response){
});
```

How can I send 2 hashtags? I have tried each of the below but they do not work.

```
hashtag: '#TestHash1#TestHash1'
hashtag: '#TestHash1 #TestHash1'
hashtag: ['#TestHash1', '#TestHash1']
```

Comment: I believe you can only use one hashtag. The documentation states: `A hashtag specified by the developer to be added to the shared content...` which also implies singular only.

Comment: Is there other method to state 2 hashtags?

Comment: @luay I can't even get the one hashtag example you provide to work. [FB's Share Dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#params) says it accepts the hashtag parameter but I don't see it when I try it.

Comment: @benrifkah did you succeed with hashtag? I have same issue: I don't see it too

Comment: @equicolor, Nope, sorry.

Comment: http://www.fbrell.com/Sharing/2%20-%20FB.ui%20Dialogs see this link..edit and add <script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    hashtag: '#hello#recipe#hehehehe',
quote: 'yoyoyy'
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>

Comment: @benrifkah, @equicolor.
You can only add one hashtag and in my tests, you should use %23 instead of #.
Example:
`%23testhashtag`

Answer (score 5):

Facebook has updated their [policies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/overview/). so now we can provide **a Hashtag** and no more.